# Checking list item hover states to trigger an action - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 images in an unordered list. Ideally I want to be able to load all the list items into an array and do a check to see which one is currently hovered.

I know using the jQuery is() function I can check which is in an :hover state. How would I apply this check to all items within that list array?

```
<ul class="image-list">
    <li class="image-item"><img src="/image1.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="image-item"><img src="/image1.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="image-item"><img src="/image1.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="image-item"><img src="/image1.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help.

DIM3NSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `mouseover()` function:

```
// Add mouseover event to all your image-items
$('.image-list > .image-item').mouseover(function() {
    // $(this) is your hovered image-item object
    alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));    
});
```

**Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/q46gxnzu/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/758/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var li = $("ul li"); //get all li. All li are stored in an array.
    $(document).on("mouseover", "ul li.image-item", function (e) {
        var ele = $(this); //get currently hovered li.
        var item = li.index(ele); //get the index of the currently hovered li in that array
        console.log(item); //this logs the index. Using this index, do whatever you want with that item.
    });
});
```